# Make event function wait until UpdatePanel async postback has completed in codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have a WebForm that has an `UpdatePanel` updating a data value. I also have a button underneath that calls a function in CodeBehind that will use the value in the `UpdatePanel` as a value.

So far, the code works perfectly, but if I `Trigger` an update to the panel and then quickly click the button, if done fast enough, can cause a runtime error because the `Click` event executes quicker than the `UpdatePanel` and finishes before the async operation.

I have tried adding `updatePanel.Update()` at the top of the function, but obviously this is starting a new process rather than forcing a wait of the existing process.

How can I get my function to wait for the async task to complete in the code behind?

**Async function triggered by UpdatePanel (sets `hfDeleteAppID` value to 1)**

```vb
    Protected Sub btn_A1_Sub_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_A1_Sub.Click
        If btn_A1_Sub.CssClass = "fas fa-lg fa-times-circle" Then
            hfDeleteAppID.Value = 1
        Else
            applicationTransactions.saveUserApplication(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId(), 1)
            dgYourApps.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub
```

**Function being called (needs to use the value of `hfDeleteAppID`)**

```vb
    Protected Sub App_Delete(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        upApplications.Update()

        Dim appID As Double = hfDeleteAppID.Value

        applicationTransactions.deleteApplication(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId(), appID)
        dgYourApps.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Comment: I don´t see any async code here. You should declare your events `async void` and  `await upApplications.Update()`

Comment: The first function is being executed when the `UpdatePanel Trigger` is triggered to asynchronously update that part of the page and the second function is called when a button is clicked. So the code itself isn't asynchronous, but the process is.

Comment: You could use a [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netcore-3.1). Call `SetResult` in `btn_A1_Sub_Click` and await its Task in `App_Delete`. Or you call the `Result` property of the task but this will block your Main Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a TaskCompletionSource field, instantiate and await it in the Delete handler which have to be change to `async`.

```
Dim tcs As TaskCompletionSource(Of Boolean)
...

Protected Async Sub App_Delete(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    tcs = new TaskCompletionSource(Of Boolean)

    upApplications.Update()
    
    'Wait until btn_A1_Sub_Click has finished
    await tcs.Task

    Dim appID As Double = hfDeleteAppID.Value

    applicationTransactions.deleteApplication(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId(), appID)
    dgYourApps.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Set the Result of the TCS in the button click handler:

```
 Protected Sub btn_A1_Sub_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_A1_Sub.Click
        If btn_A1_Sub.CssClass = "fas fa-lg fa-times-circle" Then
            hfDeleteAppID.Value = 1
        Else
            applicationTransactions.saveUserApplication(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId(), 1)
            dgYourApps.DataBind()
        End If
        'Set the tcs to completed
        'Do some checks her and set result to false in case of error e.g.
        If tcs IsNot Nothing Then
           tcs.SetResult(True)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Instead of having a TCS of type boolean you can for sure declare it as double and set the result of `hfDeleteAppID` directly.